# Need to select the visible DOM element when mouse scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are 5 more images in a page on my site in different position. I need to animate them when they are visible. Just need to select the specific image which are just visible when scrolling mouse using jQuery. Is there any way to to get the current element of a DOM?

Please help me.

Comment: yes. it's possible. ON MOUSE HOVER EVENT: you can try to get this.elementTarget... or something like that

Comment: I need to select the image when mouse scrolling which are just now focusing..

Comment: $('img').on('scroll', function(){
    HEREISMYEL= $(this);
});

Answer (score 1):

You can use the  `jquery.appear` plugin

It implements custom appear/disappear events which are fired when an element becomes visible/invisible in the browser viewport.

Example:-

```
 $('Div1').on('appear', function(event, $all_appeared_elements) {
      // this element is now inside browser viewport
    });



   $('Div1').on('disappear', function(event, $all_disappeared_elements) {
      // this element is now outside browser viewport
    });
```

Read more on https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear